# How to open a file that everyday has a different name due to date change

Tags: python, csv

I am working on an automation of reporting to my collaborators.

I am pulling the report though API with the following code:

***code***

```
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)

app_id = 'myappid'
report_type = 'daily_report'

params = {
  'api_token': 'api_token',
  'from': yesterday,
  'to': yesterday
}

request_url = 'https://domainxyz.com/export/{}/{}/v5'.format(app_id, report_type)

res = requests.request('GET', request_url, params=params)

if res.status_code != 200:
  if res.status_code == 404:
    print('There is a problem with the request URL. Make sure that it is correct')
  else:
    print('There was a problem retrieving data: ', res.text)
else:
  f = open('{}-{}-{}-to-{}.csv'.format(app_id, report_type, params['from'], params['to']), 'w', newline='', encoding="utf-8")
  f.write(res.text)
  f.close()
```

and the code saves the file as 'myappid-daily_report-yesterdayDate-to-yesterdayDate.csv

and this is working just great.
Once I do have the data for yesterday, I would like to open the csv file and do some modifications with Pandas but before this, I need to open the CSV file which has kind of a dynamic name on daily basis.

I would open the file with the following

```
import csv
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)

app_id = 'myappid'
report_type = 'daily_report'

params = {

  'from': yesterday,
  'to': yesterday
}


csv_file = ('{}-{}-{}-to-{}'.format(app_id, report_type, params['from'], params['to']))
print (csv_file)

with open('csv_file' +'.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
```

The print function returns proper name but I am getting an error which says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Iwan/PycharmProjects/Learning/csv_mods.py", line 20, in <module>
    with open('csv_file' +'.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'csv_file.csv'
```

So I wonder how can I inject the *.csv on daily basis instead of manually typing csv file name.

If I have made any mistake in this post or question please point it out and I will do my best to avoid this in the future.

Comment: Presumably you meant to use the _variable name_ csv_file as the base filename, not the literal string `'csv_file'`.

Comment: When I started, I didn't realize that I needed to specify the entire path to the file. You'll need something like `'C:/Users/Iwan/.../csv_file.csv'`

Comment: @DanWhite That is not *necessarily* the case, but it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two changes that will have to be made that are jumping out at me right away.

First of all, you're trying to open the file with the name defined by your variable `csv_file`, but you wrapped the variable name in quotes in your `open()` statement:

```
with open('csv_file' +'.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
```

Remove the quotes around `csv_file`, so that it uses the value of the variable `csv_file`, rather than just the literal string `'csv_file'`:

```
with open(csv_file + '.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
```

Second, you'll almost certainly want to change the way the `datetime` string gets formatted, because `yesterday` is just a `datetime.datetime` object, so it's string representation will look something hideous like `'2019-12-04 16:21:36.731000'`, which isn't a very good string to put in a filename.

I'm going to take a guess that your filename will want dates formatted something like `YYYYMMDD`, but since you haven't given us that information there's not much to go on. Assuming that case, you could change the way you get your value for `yesterday` to be a string formatted from the `datetime.datetime` object, using `datetime.datetime.strftime()`:

```
yesterday = (today - timedelta(days = 1)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: In fact the date format I'm getting with current code is : YYYY-MM-DD which seems to be fine to me. I also appreciate your detailed explanation on the issue.